# What is the source of this event in Snowpiercer?

Tags: snowpiercer

Towards the end of *Snowpiercer*,

> there is some catastrophic explosion that floods everything with the fire, eventually even causing avalanche in the mountain nearby.

Where is it coming from? This does not look like done by

> some improvised bomb that should only open the locked door.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is caused by it.

> Not exactly by the explosion itself, but due to the sound waves. These shock waves cause the avalanche in the surrounding mountains, then the avalanche strikes and derails the train, destroying many of the cars and killing almost everyone inside of them.